# convert phprecord to excel using Phpexcel very slow

Tags: php, performance, codeigniter, phpexcel

I have an issue using phpexcel. I must convert records to excel and download. Problem is the process is very slow. I tested with 2000 - 3000 records, set Time Limit to 0, and Memory limit to 256M, but it needs more than about 30 minutes to process and download. I have seen others on the web that can download about 6000 records just in 10 seconds.

Please, someone, help me. What's wrong with the code?

**This is the Controller :**

```
function download_aplikasi()
{
    $this->Weblog_m->save_log_m("Download aplikasi");
    $data_aplikasi = $this->Io_excel_m->get_aplikasi_m();
    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('1:1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

    // Add some data
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'TGL_APLIKASI')
        ->setCellValue('B1', 'CD_CABANG')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'NAMA_CABANG')
        ->setCellValue('D1', 'NIP')
        ->setCellValue('E1', 'NAMA_PEGAWAI')
        ->setCellValue('F1', 'JABATAN')
        ->setCellValue('G1', 'NAMA_NASABAH')
        ->setCellValue('H1', 'NO_REK')
        ->setCellValue('I1', 'NO_CIF')
        ->setCellValue('J1', 'DOB_NASABAH')
        ->setCellValue('K1', 'JNS_NASABAH')
        ->setCellValue('L1', 'NOMINAL')
        ->setCellValue('M1', 'ID_NASABAH')
        ->setCellValue('N1', 'PRODUK')
        ->setCellValue('O1', 'JNS_PINJAMAN')
        ->setCellValue('P1', 'JNS_USAHA')
        ->setCellValue('Q1', 'LAMA_USAHA')
        ->setCellValue('R1', 'JNS_JAMINAN')
        ->setCellValue('S1', 'PIC_NASABAH')
        ->setCellValue('T1', 'TELP_NASABAH')
        ->setCellValue('U1', 'NAMA_TOKO')
        ->setCellValue('V1', 'KATEGORI')
        ->setCellValue('W1', 'CATATAN')
        ->setCellValue('X1', 'KETERANGAN')
        ->setCellValue('Y1', 'PIC_UNIT')
        ->setCellValue('Z1', 'TELP_PIC')
        ->setCellValue('AA1', 'KAT_PRODUK')
        ->setCellValue('AB1', 'PROGRESS')
        ->setCellValue('AC1', 'PROGRESS_NOTE');

    $i = 1;
    if (count($data_aplikasi) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($data_aplikasi as $row_aplikasi)
        {
            $data_pic = $this->App_m->detilpic_m($row_aplikasi->idpic);
            $i = $i + 1;
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A'.$i, date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row_aplikasi->tglaplikasi)))
                ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $row_aplikasi->cdcabang)
                ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $row_aplikasi->namacabang)
                ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $row_aplikasi->nip)
                ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $row_aplikasi->nama_user)
                ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $row_aplikasi->namajabatan)
                ->setCellValue('G'.$i, $row_aplikasi->nama_nasabah)
                ->setCellValue('H'.$i, $row_aplikasi->norek)
                ->setCellValue('I'.$i, $row_aplikasi->nocif)
                ->setCellValue('J'.$i, $row_aplikasi->tgllahir)
                ->setCellValue('K'.$i, $row_aplikasi->jnsnasabah)
                ->setCellValue('L'.$i, $row_aplikasi->nominal_aplikasi)
                ->setCellValue('M'.$i, $row_aplikasi->ktpnasabah)
                ->setCellValue('N'.$i, $row_aplikasi->produk)
                ->setCellValue('O'.$i, $row_aplikasi->jnspinjaman)
                ->setCellValue('P'.$i, $row_aplikasi->jnsusaha)
                ->setCellValue('Q'.$i, $row_aplikasi->lamausaha)
                ->setCellValue('R'.$i, $row_aplikasi->jnsjaminan)
                ->setCellValue('S'.$i, $row_aplikasi->pic_nasabah)
                ->setCellValue('T'.$i, $row_aplikasi->telpnasabah)
                ->setCellValue('U'.$i, $row_aplikasi->namatoko)
                ->setCellValue('V'.$i, $row_aplikasi->kategori)
                ->setCellValue('W'.$i, $row_aplikasi->catatan)
                ->setCellValue('X'.$i, $row_aplikasi->keterangan)
                ->setCellValue('Y'.$i, $data_pic->nama_user)
                ->setCellValue('Z'.$i, $data_pic->nomorhp)
                ->setCellValue('AA'.$i, $row_aplikasi->namaproduct)
                ->setCellValue('AB'.$i, $row_aplikasi->progress)
                ->setCellValue('AC'.$i, $row_aplikasi->progress_note);
        }
    }
    else $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A2', 'No Record Found');

    // Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Aplikasi');


    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Aplikasi_'.$this->input->post("bulan_kinerja").'.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
}
```

**This is the Model:**

```
function get_aplikasi_m()
{
    $periode = $this->input->post("bulan_kinerja");
    $idcabang = $this->input->post("id_cabang");
    $cek_cabang = $this->cek_cabang_m($idcabang);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from("tbl_aplikasi");
    $this->db->join("tbl_user", "tbl_user.iduser = tbl_aplikasi.iduser", "Left");
    $this->db->join("tbl_product", "tbl_product.idproduct = tbl_aplikasi.idproduct", "Left");
    $this->db->join("tbl_jabatan", "tbl_user.idjabatan = tbl_jabatan.idjabatan", "Left");
    $this->db->join("tbl_unit", "tbl_product.idunit = tbl_unit.idunit", "Left");
    $this->db->join("tbl_cabang", "tbl_user.idcabang = tbl_cabang.idcabang", "Left");
    $this->db->where("tbl_aplikasi.statusapproval='approve'");
    $this->db->where("MONTH(tbl_aplikasi.tglaplikasi)", date("m", strtotime($periode)));
    $this->db->where("YEAR(tbl_aplikasi.tglaplikasi)", date("Y", strtotime($periode)));

    if ($cek_cabang->jnscabang != "area") $this->db->where("tbl_aplikasi.idcabang", $idcabang);

    $this->db->order_by("tbl_aplikasi.tglaplikasi", "desc");
    return $query = $this->db->get()->result();
}

function getpic_m($idunit)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from("tbl_user");
    $this->db->join("tbl_jabatan", "tbl_user.idjabatan = tbl_jabatan.idjabatan", "Left");
    $this->db->join("tbl_cabang", "tbl_cabang.idcabang = tbl_user.idcabang", "Left");
    $this->db->where("tbl_user.idunit", $idunit);
    $this->db->where("tbl_user.accstat='active'");
    $this->db->order_by("tbl_user.nama_user", "asc");
    return $query = $this->db->get();
}
```

Comment: you've to evaluate which process takes this time... try it with the benchmarking class of ci and you'll find the problem pretty much soon (other than that - xdebug is a tool, to find such weak spots - but you need a supporting IDE for that) - take a look here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/benchmark.html

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel is old and not maintained. It has been replaced with a new version called [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) and you should be using that version. For me, it has been faster and more reliable.

It is easy to convert because most of the functions are exactly the same. There won't be a lot of re-writing required. The main change is in creating readers, writers, workbook and sheet objects.

I will stay with PHPExcel for this answer.

There are a few things you can do to optimize the code. First, capture the active sheet object for reuse instead of repeatedly calling `setActiveSheetIndex()` and `getActiveSheet()`.

```
// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
// A new workbook always sets the active sheet index to the first sheet
// Capture the "active sheet" object for easy reuse.
$activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
```

Whenever possible try to set blocks of cell values using an array instead of multiple calls to `setCellValue()`. For example:

```
// Add some data
$rowArray = ['TGL_APLIKASI', 'CD_CABANG', 'NAMA_CABANG', 'NIP',
    'NAMA_PEGAWAI', 'JABATAN', 'NAMA_NASABAH', 'NO_REK', 'NO_CIF',
    'DOB_NASABAH', 'JNS_NASABAH', 'NOMINAL', 'ID_NASABAH', 'PRODUK',
    'JNS_PINJAMAN', 'JNS_USAHA', 'LAMA_USAHA', 'JNS_JAMINAN',
    'PIC_NASABAH', 'TELP_NASABAH', 'NAMA_TOKO', 'KATEGORI',
    'CATATAN', 'KETERANGAN', 'PIC_UNIT', 'TELP_PIC', 'KAT_PRODUK', 
    'PROGRESS', 'PROGRESS_NOTE'];

//add the array to the activesheet
$activeSheet->fromArray($rowArray, NULL, 'A1');
```

Read about [Setting a Range of Cells from an Array](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#setting-a-range-of-cells-from-an-array)

You can use `fromArray()` to add the database results too but it will require a change in the model. Your model uses `result()` which returns an array of objects. If you return `result_array()` instead it will be easy to use the data to apply all the rows with one call.

Change the last line of `function get_aplikasi_m()` to this

```
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

You have two complications though. First is the formatting of the date in the first column. You could, and probably should revise your query to do that during data retrieval. But I won't show how to do that.

The second complication is adding the `$data_pic` items. It would be easier if `App_m->detilpic_m()` returned `result_array()` but I will proceed with it as-is.

Adding the rows and columns from the model data then looks like this.

```
$data_aplikasi = $this->Io_excel_m->get_aplikasi_m();
if (count($data_aplikasi) > 0)
{
    //walk through all records to format date and add pic data
    foreach ($data_aplikasi as $key => $row_aplikasi)
    {
        // format the date and make sure the 
        // main array is updated with the change
        $data_aplikasi[$key]['tglaplikasi'] = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row_aplikasi['tglaplikasi']));

        $data_pic = $this->App_m->detilpic_m($row_aplikasi['idpic']);
        //make an array from $data_pic values
        $pic_data = [$data_pic->nama_user, $data_pic->nomorhp];
        //get the index where pic data should be inserted
        $index = array_search("keterangan", array_keys($row_aplikasi));
        // insert $pic_data into $row_aplikasi at the right place 
        // and update the model result at the same time
        $data_aplikasi[$key] = array_splice($row_aplikasi, $index, 0, $pic_data);
    }
    //add $data_aplikasi array to the activesheet with one call
    $activeSheet->fromArray($data_aplikasi, NULL, 'A2');
}
else
{
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A2', 'No Record Found');
}
```

I hope the comments make it clear what is happening. Here is the whole function so you can see it all at once.

```
public function download_aplikasi()
{
    $this->Weblog_m->save_log_m("Download aplikasi");
    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    // A new workbook always sets the active sheet index to the first sheet
    // Capture the "active sheet" object sheet
    $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    // Name the worksheet
    $activeSheet->setTitle('Aplikasi');

    $activeSheet->getStyle('1:1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

    // Add some data
    $rowArray = ['TGL_APLIKASI', 'CD_CABANG', 'NAMA_CABANG', 'NIP',
        'NAMA_PEGAWAI', 'JABATAN', 'NAMA_NASABAH', 'NO_REK', 'NO_CIF',
        'DOB_NASABAH', 'JNS_NASABAH', 'NOMINAL', 'ID_NASABAH', 'PRODUK',
        'JNS_PINJAMAN', 'JNS_USAHA', 'LAMA_USAHA', 'JNS_JAMINAN',
        'PIC_NASABAH', 'TELP_NASABAH', 'NAMA_TOKO', 'KATEGORI',
        'CATATAN', 'KETERANGAN', 'PIC_UNIT', 'TELP_PIC', 'KAT_PRODUK',
        'PROGRESS', 'PROGRESS_NOTE'];

    //add the array to the activesheet
    $activeSheet->fromArray($rowArray, NULL, 'A1');


    $data_aplikasi = $this->Io_excel_m->get_aplikasi_m();
    if (count($data_aplikasi) > 0)
    {
        //walk through all records to format date and add pic data
        foreach ($data_aplikasi as $key => $row_aplikasi)
        {
            // format the date and make sure the 
            // main array is updated with the change
            $data_aplikasi[$key]['tglaplikasi'] = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row_aplikasi['tglaplikasi']));

            $data_pic = $this->App_m->detilpic_m($row_aplikasi['idpic']);
            //make an array from $data_pic values
            $pic_data = [$data_pic->nama_user, $data_pic->nomorhp];
            //get the index where pic data should be inserted
            $index = array_search("keterangan", array_keys($row_aplikasi));
            // insert $pic_data into $row_aplikasi at the right place 
            // and update the model result at the same time
            $data_aplikasi[$key] = array_splice($row_aplikasi, $index, 0, $pic_data);
        }
        //add $data_aplikasi array to the activesheet with one call
        $activeSheet->fromArray($data_aplikasi, NULL, 'A2');
    }
    else
    {
        $activeSheet->setCellValue('A2', 'No Record Found');
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Aplikasi_'.$this->input->post("bulan_kinerja").'.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    //Don't use exit, let CI finish as designed by letting the controller return
    //exit;
}
```

I have assumed that `$this->Io_excel_m->get_aplikasi_m()` returns the fields in the order you used them in your original code. If fields are not in that order you will either have to rearrange `$data_aplikasi` or change the query so the fields are in the order you want. Personally, I would do the second.

It is hard to tell for sure, but it looks like you could modify the query (using a JOIN) to get the `$data_pic` fields during the call to `get_aplikasi_m()`.

The date field could be returned from the query in the format you want too.

Those two model changes would eliminate the `foreach` loop used to modify `data_aplikasi`. Execution will be faster because you remove the thousands of database calls to get `$data_pic`. As a rule it is best not to make queries inside a loop - it requires a lot system resources and time.

I have not tested this code (no data) so it is very possible there are logic and syntax errors. The concept is sound and is a technique I have used successfully.